# How do I wire my 4066N analogue switch

Tags: switches, pinout

I plan to use one of these to throw two switches at the same time:

http://www.digikey.ca/product-detail/en/74HCT4066N,112/568-7854-5-ND/1230913

The switches should be closed when the voltage from this debounced circuit is high:

[Which diode to use on my RC switch debounce circuit?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/135995/which-diode-to-use-on-my-rc-switch-debounce-circuit)

This is the pin layout from the switch documentation:

[image: 4066N Pin layout]

Which wires connect to which pins? These are all the wires I will use:

- 5V DC [pin 14, Vcc]
- Ground [pin 7, GND]
- Schmitt Trigger output [???]
- Circuit 1 wire 1 [???]
- Circuit 1 wire 2 [???]
- Circuit 2 wire 1 [???]
- Circuit 2 wire 2 [???]

Upon trigger, I would like Circuit 1 wire 1 and wire 2 to be connected at the same time that Circuit 2 wire 1 and wire 2 are connected.

Please let me know if anything else seems wrong with what I'm trying to do here. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each of the nY and nZ connections are connected internally, with the nE pin controlling them. So, connect both wires of circuit 1 to nY and nZ pins with the same value for n, do the same for both wires of circuit 2, connect the control output to the corresponding nE pins, and tie the other two enables high or low.

And of course make sure that the circuits do not violate the absolute maximums given in the datasheet.

Comment: And connect the unused inputs to GND...

Comment: @MarkU: The enables, yes. The Y and Z inputs are connected to sources and drains instead of gates and so don't suffer the same problem as normal inputs.

Comment: Hmm, tried it out, but I'm having a problem where the switch is rapidly switching ON/OFF as described [here](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/149776/4066n-analogue-switch-rapidly-switching-on-off-when-should-be-off)...